# designing a star schema

Tags: sql-server, star-schema

I am a newbie and would appreciate suggestions/material to research

I have 3 types on information in a single table

1. problems
2. reasons
3. fixes

problem data is related to reasons by 1 to many

reasons data is related to fixes by 1 to many

I am thinking of creating a dimension table for dates as mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224520/design-star-schema-for-relatonal-database?newreg=a28ef95e5471417c90ef384292a94eaf)

How could I design a star schema out of it? As of now the entire data is in a single table (all joined together)

#####################
update 1 - example data and my 1st solution below. Please guide

my columns are

```
problem id
problem description
problem associate department
problem due date
reason id
reason description
reason associated person
reason due date
fix id
fix description
fix owning employee
fix due date
```

example data

[image]

```
+------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| problem id | problem description | problem associate department | problem due date | reason id |    reason description    | reason associated person | reason due date | fix id |   fix description    | fix owning employee | fix due date |
+------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|          1 | wrong customer info | sales                        | 1-Jan-21         |         1 | customer gave wrong info | a                        | 15-Dec-20       |      1 | contact customer     | bb                  | 10-Dec-20    |
|          1 | wrong customer info | sales                        | 1-Jan-21         |         2 | customer gave wrong info | a                        | 15-Dec-20       |      2 | verify customer info | cc                  | 15-Dec-20    |
|          1 | wrong customer info | sales                        | 1-Jan-21         |         1 | data entry error         | b                        | 16-Dec-20       |      1 | correct data entry   | bb                  | 16-Dec-20    |
|          1 | wrong customer info | sales                        | 1-Jan-21         |         1 | database wrong join      | c                        | 20-Dec-20       |      1 | fix join             | aa                  | 19-Dec-20    |
|          1 | wrong customer info | sales                        | 1-Jan-21         |         2 | database wrong join      | c                        | 20-Dec-20       |      2 | something else       | dd                  | 19-Dec-20    |
|          1 | wrong customer info | sales                        | 1-Jan-21         |         3 | database wrong join      | c                        | 20-Dec-20       |      3 | modify tables        | bb                  | 19-Dec-20    |
+------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

I am thinking of a design like below. all joins would be 1:1 in case of `fact table`. In case of `fact table2 calendar` there would be 1:many join as that fact table would have one row per date while the dim tables could have same date on multiple rows

[image]

Comment: I would recommend reading: The Data Warehouse Toolkit : The Complete Guide to Dimensional Modeling by Ralph Kimball and Margy Ross

Comment: "I have 3 tables" doesn't go with "now the entire data is in a single table". Do you have 3 tables or 1 table? Do you have a unique identifier now or do you still have to create one? I suggest you to share the structure of that table maybe changing the column name

Answer (score 2):

A very basic star-schema for your situation might look like this:

[image]

The T-SQL statements to create the dimension tables for this schema look like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.problems
(
    problem_id int NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT problems_pk
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , problem_description nvarchar(400) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.reasons
(
    reason_id int NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT reasons_pk
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , problem_id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT reasons_problem_fk
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.problems(problem_id)
    , reason_text nvarchar(500) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.fixes 
(
    fix_id int NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT fixes_pk
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , reason_id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fixes_reason_fk
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.reasons(reason_id)
    , fix_text nvarchar(525) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.dates
(
    date_id int NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT dates_pk
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , starting_date datetime NOT NULL
    , ending_date datetime NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT dates_dates
        CHECK (ending_date > starting_date)
);
```

The fact table, which you seem to have left out of your question, and I've named `incidents`, looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.incidents
(
    incident_id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT incidents_pk
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , incident_date_id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT incidents_incident_date
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.dates (date_id)
    , problem_id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT incidents_problem_fk
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.problems(problem_id)
    , fix_id int NULL
        CONSTRAINT incidents_fix_fk
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.fixes(fix_id)
    , fix_date_id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT incidents_fix_date
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.dates (date_id)
);
```

`incidents` references the dimension tables such that you are storing the bare minimum of information in the fact table.  The `fix_id` column is referenced in the `incidents` table to indicate which of the possibly many fixes was accepted as the actual fix used in this incident.  Since each fix is related to only a single reason, you can infer the reason from the fix.  I've included a discrete column to indicate the problem in this table to enable incidents that don't yet have a fix.

You could add a `reason_id` foreign-key column to the `incidents` table if desired.  For instance, maybe you identify a reason prior to determining the fix.